# React Native Firebase. After pushing data to firebase database I get null instead of snapshot in then()

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux, react-native-firebase

I use React Native Firebase for working with Firebase.
In redux action I have:

```
export const startAction = (item) => {


    return (dispatch) => {

        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/some/`)
            .push(item).then((snapshot) => {
                console.log('Added to firebase', snapshot,  snapshot.key);

            }).catch((err) => { console.log('errooooor', err) });
    }


}
```

In **then()** I should get **snapshot** of inserted data, but I get **null**. How is that possible?

Error text: **Cannot read property 'key' of null**

Comment: What Firebase version are you using?

Comment: This is a known bug, we'll get it fixed for v5.1.0 - thanks!

Comment: React Native Firebase - 4.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Firebase docs (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/database/reference/Reference#push), `Reference.push()` does not return a promise. It returns a reference.

If you would like to know when the write to the server is complete, you can pass a callback function as a second parameter to the `.push()` function.

```
export const startAction = (item) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/some/`)
            .push(item, error => {
                if (!error)
                    console.log("Item added to firebase");
                else
                    console.warn("There was an error writing to the database, error);
            })
    }
}
```

EDIT: Based on Salakar's comments here and on [this Github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/893#issuecomment-411785191):

> without the await is also correct as creating a new reference + id path via push() is synchronous/client sided

You should be able to do the following:

```
const ref = firebase.database()
                .ref(`/users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/some/`)
                .push(item)
// Now do something with `ref.key`
```

Comment: This is a known bug, we'll get it fixed for v5.1.0 - thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you will make `.push()` return a promise. Is that correct?

Comment: It'll be made to match the Firebase Web SDK, see: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/893

Comment: I need to know not just when the write to the server is completed, but I need to know ID of inserted data set, so that I could save it to Redux store. Work is stopped, what to do? Delete RNFB and use original library?

Comment: Is there any way to know inserted data ID right after firebase query?

Comment: Salakar, what is your thanks for? What is temp solution? How to get ID of pushed item and do something after that?

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution. Check it out @JohnSmith